# Available tag in ant is always true if a file is unavailable also

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

This code is always returning a true value even if file at given path does not exists

```
   <available file="${x}/schema/@{componentname}-schema.sql" type="file"      property="schema.file" />
      <if>
          <equals arg1="true" arg2="${schema.file}" />
            <then>
        <debug message="****schemafile is  ${schema.file} ******" />
            </then>
</if>
```

Output is always :-
****schemafile is  true******

even if file is not available at that path.
Please help me to find the error.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't just missing that there is no output if the file doesn't exist?

Comment: no..I was iterating through this code, and if once ${schema.file} is set to true,in the next iteration if file is not found, will this be defaulted to true?

Comment: My point was that your debug output is inside the if block which is only executed if `${schema.file}` is true. So either your output is `****schemafile is  true ******` or nothing at all. It cannot be `****schemafile is  false ******` if that's what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem  was i was iterating above code in for loop, and since property is immutable, it is always set to true if set at-least once. Thats why after 1 iteration even if the file was not found, it echoes *schemafile is true*** .

i have added below code to set property to false after that code

```
<var name="schema.file" unset="true"/>
<property name="schema.file" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've refactored your example, in order to use standard ANT tasks:

```
<project name="demo" default="run" xmlns:if="ant:if">

  <property name="src.dir" location="src"/>

  <target name="run">
    <available file="${src.dir}/schema/schema.sql" type="file" property="schema.file" />
    <echo message="****schemafile is  ${schema.file} ******" if:set="schema.file"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- I don't recognise the "debug" task so use the standard "echo" task instead
- I recommend not using the ant-contrib "if" task. ANT 1.9.1 introduced an [if attribute](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) which can be used instead.

The following alternative variant will work with older versions of ANT. It uses an "if" [target attribute](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html) to perform conditional execution:

```
<project name="demo" default="run">

  <property name="src.dir" location="src"/>
  <available file="${src.dir}/schema/schema.sql" type="file" property="schema.file" />

  <target name="run" if="schema.file">
    <echo message="****schemafile is  ${schema.file} ******"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Comment: If you want to use the new if: and unless: attributes you should upgrade to Ant 1.9.3 because of https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55885 and https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55359

Comment: @Rebse Thanks for the tip! I upgraded from 1.9.0 to 1.9.3 tonight so did not realise it was broken.

Comment: Me too (running Ant 1.9.1) :-) realized today that there was also a misleading bug in the documentation in Ant 1.9.1 => https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55971